# Duplicate plugins.sbt for multi project build

Tags: scala, playframework

If in a Play application I create multiple projects, do I need to copy the file `plugins.sbt` into each one?

Or is it enough if I keep only one, in the root folder of the project?

Comment: Are you using [sub projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html) or your projects are completely independent from each other?

Comment: The projects are completely independent.

Comment: Then yes, you will need a `plugins.sbt` for each project. But I think you can/should read how SBT handles multi-projects: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html